# Galaxy mini S5570 automatically creates screenshots

Tags: screenshots, troubleshooting

It makes screenshots on its own and saves them in the gallery. I delete them but it makes new screenshots.

I stopped an running app that says "screen capture" but it does it again. I can't delete it, it's not an installed app.

What can I do do permanently stop this nonsense?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe its being caused by a certain combination of buttons at the bottom of the screen. I haven't found a workaround, but here is something you can do to, at least not to store images (its not much, but something). It creates a directory "ScreenCaptures" to store images in; if you delete it, it will be simply recreated. So, instead, in the same directory, create a file with that name. Every time a screen is captured, it will complain that it cannot be stored, so at least you won't have to worry about deleting those images.

Comment: When you say "So, instead, in the same directory, create a file with that name," what is "that name"?

Comment: @dotVezz same name as a folder, "ScreenCaptures"